# Is it possible to use SVG foreignObject as a mask?

Tags: svg, mask

The text element inside the mask works as expected, but the div inside the foreignObject element is ignored.

```
<svg width='500' height='300' >  
  <defs>
    <mask id='m'>
      <text fill='white' x='0' y='35' font-size='35'>text element</text>
      <foreignObject  width='200' height='200' >
         <div style='color:white;'>div element</div>
      </foreignObject>
  </mask>
</defs>
      <rect width='200' height='200' mask='url(#m)' />
</svg>
```

Does anyone know how to get the foreignObject to work inside a mask?  Is it even possible?

Comment: nobody knows... Is it?

Comment: Good question. `foreignObject` is not usable as a mask as far as I have experimented in Chrome recently.