# SVG mask not visible

Tags: svg

```
<svg viewBox="1.75 1.75 20.5 20.5" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
        <mask id="myMask">
            <foreignObject width="600px" height="600px">
                <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                    <head>
                        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
                        <style type="text/css">
                            div {
                                width: 5000px;
                                height: 5000px;
                                background-color: #ff0000;
                            }
                        </style>
                    </head>
                    <body>
                        <div></div>
                    </body>
                </html>
            </foreignObject>
        </mask>
    </defs>
<path d="M22.25 12c0-1.43-.88-2.67-2.19-3.34.46-1.39.2-2.9-.81-3.91s-2.52-1.27-3.91-.81c-.66-1.31-1.91-2.19-3.34-2.19s-2.67.88-3.33 2.19c-1.4-.46-2.91-.2-3.92.81s-1.26 2.52-.8 3.91c-1.31.67-2.2 1.91-2.2 3.34s.89 2.67 2.2 3.34c-.46 1.39-.21 2.9.8 3.91s2.52 1.26 3.91.81c.67 1.31 1.91 2.19 3.34 2.19s2.68-.88 3.34-2.19c1.39.45 2.9.2 3.91-.81s1.27-2.52.81-3.91c1.31-.67 2.19-1.91 2.19-3.34zm-11.71 4.2L6.8 12.46l1.41-1.42 2.26 2.26 4.8-5.23 1.47 1.36-6.2 6.77z" mask="url(#myMask)"/>
</svg>
```

I added an html div with foreignObject to my svg mask but the mask looks empty Did I make a rule mistake in SVG?

Comment: I haven't used it much because it's buggy as hell and inconsistent across browsers, but AFAIK, foreignObject is treated like an iframe by SVG, so you can't use its alpha channel as a mask.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47911938/is-it-possible-to-use-svg-foreignobject-as-a-mask